# raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi, uwsgi

I am making a web server controlled `raspberry pi`, so my friends can remotely control the robot over my web domain.

Having followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/12/running-flask-under-nginx-raspberry-pi/) tutorial, I've managed to get the website running up until the auto-loading point. But now I am getting the below errors:

```
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: File "./flask-control.py", line 9, in <module>
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 503)
Jun 20 18:19:14 raspberrypi uwsgi[503]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 687, cores: 2)
Jun 20 18:22:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started uWSGI Service.
```

I definitely have `RPi` installed as I have been using flask without the web server just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Which step of the tutorial do you mean by 'autoloading part' ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to install RPi as root not as user and then give the www-data user that is created in the tutorial the permission to use the GPIO pins.